# PHP create temporary link to to JS file

Tags: javascript, php

Is there anyway i can generate a tempory file that will link to a js file that can then be deleted when its not required anymore.

so for example, I want to avoid having `<script src="Assets/js/app.js"></script>`
 instead i would like to having something like `<script src="hsaiw45.js></script>`

but essentially this would point to the `Assets/js/app.js` file. So i could have loads of temporary files that all link to the same js file. then i could create a temp file based on a user name when they log in and then destroy this when they log out.

Comment: For what reason? Putting the code inline is one option, another is serving it dynamically: `src="give_me_js.php?arg=qwerty">`

Comment: kind of hard to explain. I basically have 2 builds of an app. when a user logs in i decide which build to user (ADMIN OR USER) and then use JS to load a new script tag that points to the correct build. but say the build name was `<script src="Assets/js/app-user.js"></script>` they could just then inspect and change 'app-user.js' to app-admin.js to get the other build. The api routes wouldn't work but they could get an insight into the admin side of things by the extra javascript they could see. Im trying to make this hard for someone to do by making the js filenames appear kind of random

Comment: Why not use an if? `if($admin) { ... } else { ... }`?

Comment: Serve it as text with the correct content-type via php called in the `src` attribute, E.g. `if ($is_admin) echo file_get_contents("nonpublic/admin.js") else ...`

Comment: Never though about serving it as text, that would probably work for me. will give this a try thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<script src="hsaiw45.js"></script>` use something like `<script src="myjs123.php"></script>`

Then in this PHP script do the logic you need and redirect to the JS file you want.

Even more, you can do something like `<script src="myjs.php?id=123XYZ></script>` then according to the `id` key you decide which JS file to load.